# Make condition in one line?

Tags: php

Usually I made the `if/else` condition like this:

```
if(empty($data['key']))
{
    $err = "empty . $key ";
}
```

but I saw that there is the [ternary operator.](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

I really don't understand how this works.. Someone could show me an example? How can I convert this condition in the ternary logic?

Comment: The Ternary operator is documented **so much**.  Did you really need to open a new question?  Why not Google it?  `$var = (<condition> ? <value if true> : <value if false>);`

Comment: so should be like this: `$var = (empty($data['key']) $error = "empty . $key" : continue;` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: No... It is for assignment only.  You must assign to `$var`.  Please **just Google it**.  It's not that hard to understand.

Comment: Infact, seems very easy. thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your code.
You check if its empty, and then try to set `$err` to a value by concentrating an empty value.

Perhaps this is more likely what you want.

```
// Ternary operator
$err = empty($data['key']) ? "empty key" : '';
# -----------IF-----------------THEN ---- ELSE

// Ternary operator (nesting) (not recommended)
// Changing empty() to isset() you must rewrite the entire logic structure.
$err = empty($data) ? 'empty' : is_numeric($data) ? $data : 'not numeric';
# ---------IF--------- THEN -------ELSEIF-----------THEN-----ELSE

// Null Coalescing operator ?? available in PHP 7.
$err = $data['key'] ?? 'empty value';
# ---- IF ISSET USE --- ELSE value

// Nesting 
$err = $data['key'] ?? $_SESSION['key'] ?? $_COOKIE['key'] ?? 'no key';
#      IF ISSET USE -- IF ISSET USE ------ IF ISSET USE ------ELSE
```

Comment: and if I have multiple conditions to do? I want store all in the same variable, I mean after empty check is_numeric and so on.. in the same err variable how can I do this? Thanks

Comment: and for add something like `if(empty($data) && !is_numeric($data)) is possible?

Comment: Nesting ternary operations quickly pollutes code and is not recommended as its also quite hard to read. I would rather recommend an `if` statement like your comment above (yes, its possible)